# trying to send mails using code igniter and email not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

The code is not sending the email to receiver....................................

```
class Welcome extends Frontend_Controller {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
public function Subscribe_Mail() {
    $this->_Creating_subscription_mail();
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $to_email = "zzz@gmail.com";
    $from_email = trim($email);
    $config['useragent'] = "CodeIgniter";
    $config['protocol'] = "Send mail";
    $config['SMTPSecure'] = 'ssl';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'mail.XXX.com';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'rrrrr';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $config['mailpath'] = '/usr/bin/sendemail';
    $config['smtp_port'] = '587';
    $config['smtp_timeout'] = '5';  
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['validation'] = TRUE;
    $config['web_admin_email_id'] = 'support@handwritingiih.com';
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->initialize($config);    
    $data = array();
    $data['email'] = $email;  
      $this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com', 'Servhigh');
      $this->email->to('$to_email');
      $this->email->subject('Request Email On Servhigh.com');
      $this->email->message('This is my message');
      $this->email->send();
```

I want to know what is wrong with this code in controller.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->email->to('$to_email');
```

correct this to

```
$this->email->to($to_email);
```

Example:

```
$data ="hai";
echo "$data"; // output:hai
echo '$data'; // output:$data
echo $data;   //output:hai

$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/bin/sendemail';
```

Replace

```
$config['mailpath']  = "/usr/bin/sendmail";
```

Use this its working for me

```
function send_mail()
{
    $this->load->library('email');
    $config = array();
    $config['useragent'] = "CodeIgniter";
    $config['mailpath']  = "/usr/bin/sendmail";
    $config['protocol']  = "smtp";
    $config['smtp_host'] = "smtp.sendgrid.net";
    $config['smtp_user'] = "your_user_name";
    $config['smtp_pass'] = "your_password";        
    $config['smtp_port'] = "25";
    $config['mailtype']  = 'html';
    $config['charset']   = 'utf-8';
    $config['newline']   = "\r\n";
    $config['wordwrap']  = TRUE;
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->initialize($config);        
    $this->email->subject('TEST SUBJECT');
    $this->email->message("THIS IS A TEST MESSAGE");
    $this->email->from( "yourmailid"  );        
    $this->email->to("yourmailid");
    if($this->email->send())
    {
    echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please use for print_debugger to check mail is sent or not 
echo $this->email->print_debugger();

Comment: check your smtp username and password.

Comment: i used the code and it is showing "SMTP connect() failed" .

Comment: Sure your smtp user name and password is wrong.please confirm it.

Comment: I changed the user to my own email address and it is showing this error :   0 php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Comment: Which SMTP you are using and your PHP version?
php_network_getaddresses - usually occurs, when credentials are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First check if it's trying to send or not by adding this at the end:

```
if(!$this->email->send()){
   echo "Failed to send mail":
} else {
   echo "Working... Mail Send";
}
```

And replace this:

```
$this->email->to('$to_email');
```

to this:

```
$this->email->to($to_email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code (Please change the credentials according to your requirements):

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function subscribe_mail() {
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'mail.xxx.com';
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'rrrrr';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
        $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['validate'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->initialize($config);    
        $this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
        $this->email->to('someone@example.com');
        $this->email->subject('Request Email On Servhigh.com');
        $this->email->message($this->input->post('email'));
        if($this->email->send()) {
            echo "success";
        }
        else {
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        }   
    }
}
```

First of all, I changed the name of the method from `Subscribe_Mail()` to `subscribe_mail()`.

Second, I removed `if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {` as I did not find any validation rules defined.

From the [manual](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html):

> Since you haven’t told the Form Validation class to validate anything
>   yet, it returns FALSE (boolean false) by default. The `run()` method
>   only returns TRUE if it has successfully applied your rules without
>   any of them failing.

which basically implies that **if there is no validation rule defined and if the validation is NOT successful, the `run()` method will always return `FALSE`**, thereby preventing the code inside of the `if` statement from being executed.

Third, I removed some *unnecessary configs* (which are already having the specified value by default).

Fourth, I changed `Frontend_Controller` to `CI_Controller` and removed `$this->_Creating_subscription_mail();`.

Fifth, I fixed some `{}` problems.

A side note: Though I removed the validation part for convenience sake, in real life implementation you should validate the data before processing.

Comment: Sorry I could not follow up, as I had a tough week. I made some modifications to the code. If you still have not figured out the solution, please try the code and let me know.